# Is it possible to create symlink to file?

Tags: linux, symlink

For example, there is a file *music.mp3*

Is it possible to create symlink for *music.mp3* to *http://domain.com/file.mp3*?

Thanks.

Comment: Your link gives 404 error. Do you mean symlink to a file on network?

Comment: Do you mean symlink to URL?

Comment: A symlink to a *file* and a symlink to a *URL* are two very, very different things...

Comment: @brokenfoot, yes, it's just an example.

Comment: @David, you are right - how can I create a symlink to a URL?

Comment: @MarkKorzhov: http://superuser.com/questions/277186/symlink-to-a-url

Answer (score 2):

In principle it is not possible (to have a symlink to some URL)

However, you could have a specialized [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (e.g. using [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) ..) which would query the web (perhaps using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or some other HTTP library) to get the file and its meta-data. This probably could take you weeks of development (in C). Then you could mount such a filesystem and symlink to it.

Maybe some projects exist which already provide that. Look in [httpfs](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/) (I don't know much about it).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

symlink from a file to another file is possible. But a file to a url is not possible.

refer,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link